# LaTeX challenge: how to reproduce this layout and typography

Tags: fonts, sectioning, margins, typography

I would like to create a document in latex (whatever `\documentclass`) to reproduce the layout below and its typography style. I'd like to know if there is any open font at FontSquirrel or anywhere else, like the one in the picture.

Let's break through my research in steps:

- The font seems Futura BT (see Edit 2)
- Which 'sectional header' style would you use?
- Which margins?
- Which `\documentclass` ? **memoir**?

**EDIT:** I've found the origin of the book from where the image is taken. Is a book from the [ISOTYPE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotype_(picture_language)) [collection](http://www.isotyperevisited.org/). I added a useless (for the purpose of this question) photo below.

**EDIT2:** Thanks to the comment from [thrope](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/759/thrope), using identifont I discovered that the type-face is **[Futura BT](http://www.identifont.com/similar?284)** (or BQ). I could buy a license for the font at linotype or I could find a free font like that somewhere. I'll post updates about this.

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: This might be useful for identifying the font - you answer question to narrow down a list: http://www.identifont.com/

Comment: It is a bit similar to LTC Twentieth Century, but it is hard to see in the blurry image.

I wonder if microspino also wants the holes in the text :)

Comment: I'm not sure this is much of a layout challenge in any real sense (get the font right, adjust a few parameters). Perhaps some more focused questions on aspects of the adjustments might be better?

Comment: @Joseph Do you mean It's better that I delete the question? I understand your point. I try to pose the question in a better way. I'd like to know, kerning, font-face, line height, headings, margin and a suggested document class that would be good to start reproducing the book/text page layout. Most of all I'd like to know if I could customize something similar, if It already exists.

Comment: At this stage I wouldn't necessarily close it, but would consider posting some focused questions. These are more likely to get answered than a general post, and will also be more helpful to other users. I doubt anyone is going to try to reproduce the layout you've posted exactly: asking about concepts is a better approach. You might, for example, ask about the 'sectional' header layout, how to identify a particular font, etc., perhaps including some code you've already tried.

Comment: Ok. I will try as you said.

Comment: @Joseph ... As you said added 'by concept' list of small questions.
I decided also to add a +50 bounty.

Comment: @microspino I doubt that this is a Bitstream Futura (or BQ). See the Glyphlist at http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/futura/medium/characters.html and compare the Ü and the 1 for example. It is definitely a Futura, but I am wondering which variant. A regular Futura might be sufficient, though.

Comment: It's maybe a bit late, but I want just to remark that the font is NOT Futura as claimed above. The latin small letter 'a' is definitely different in Futura. I'll do a edit in the question in order to clarify this issue.

Comment: @jjdb Sorry, but I reversed your edit; as you are convinced that the type is not Futura, write it in a comment, like you did, or even make an answer.

Comment: @Keks Dose ok, no prob. I just thought it fits to the 3rd point in "When should I edit?" in http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/editing but maybe I should not be the person to judge this; still I have the feeling this information should pop up above. Maybe deleting the EDIT2?

Comment: The typeface is certainly not Futura although it's close in spirit: look at the capital 'G' and the lowercase 'a'. The umlaut in the capital Ü is internal instead of superposed (which may be an alternate sort chosen for this setting). It's also close to (but still not) Linotype Avenir; do you know the date? The hooked top to the digit 7 is less common in sans-serif types than in seriffed ones.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm going through the list in your question, step by step.

- Regarding the font Bitstream Futura BT, that you found out, here are instructions: [Using Bitstream Futura with LaTeX](http://www.gaehrken.de/tex/bfutura.txt). It belongs to Michael Gährkens page [Bitstream-Fonts for TeX/LaTeX](http://www.gaehrken.de/tex/index.html).
- The sectioning could be designed for instance using the [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package and its commands `\titleformat` and `titlespacing`.
- Measure the margins out and specify their exact values to the [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package using its margin options. If you are not bound to that margins: a typographically very good page design could be achieved using the [`typearea`](http://ctan.org/pkg/typearea) package. It calculates the margins from a typographical point of view, letting you decide the basic page partitioning.
- `memoir` is a very capable class, but I would prefer `scrbook`. But both classes offer many ways for customization.

Comment: If you end up using `scrbook`, you don't need to use `geometry`, you can use the builtin `\areaset` to define the margins.

Comment: @Raphink Actually _all_ KOMA classes (scrbook, scrartcl,...) internally load the `typearea` package. `\areaset` is one of `typearea`'s commands.

Answer (score 11):

This seems like a fun question, although, would meta seem more apt place for these?
I hope people can contribute plain/context/etc. answers as well.

I think I got close, but no cigar (in Plain XeTeX):

```
\uselanguage{ngerman}
\def\myfont{Futura}
\font\futten="\myfont"
\font\futbf="\myfont/B"
\font\futtwelwe="\myfont" at 12pt
\font\futfourteen="\myfont" at 14pt
\futten
\def\bf{\futbf}
\baselineskip=14pt
\parindent=1.4em
\hsize=8.4cm
\setbox0=\hbox{i}
\spaceskip=\wd0 plus 0.5em minus 0.15em % to enable those gaping holes
\frenchspacing
\line{{\futfourteen Überblick}\hfil Zu Tafel 18, 19, 20, 21}
\kern.5ex
\leftline{{\futtwelwe Von 1700 bis zur Gegenwart}}
\kern1ex
Die moderne Wirlschaftsordnung ist charakterisiert durch {\bf koloniale Expansion} und {\bf Industrialisierung, bürgerliche Revolution, Beginn der proletarischen Revolution.}

Um 1700 hat Spanien mit seinen Kolonien ungefähr dieselbe Bevölkerungszahl wie Deutschland oder Frankreich, doppelt soviel wie Großbritannien samt Kolonien oder Rußland. Der gewaltigste Staat war damals China.

Von 1700 bis zur Gegenwart findet eine ungeheure Umwälzung statt auf dem Gebiet der internationalen Beziehungen, der Produktionsweise und der gesellschaftlichen Struktur; das moderne Unternehmerturn bildet sich heraus auf dem Boden des Handels, des Kolonial- und Fabrikwesens. Entwicklung des Proletariats. Die führende Macht war zunächst das Britische Reich, dessen Hauptkonkurrent gegenwärtig die U.S.A. sind.
\bye
```

[image]

At least the font is wrong; the original seems a bit wider. I was using whatever Futura that came with OSX. Also, I didn't measure anything, just went ahead with the first setting that looked somewhat similar. Also, I don't know how to read the German language, so if I made mistakes reading that blurry image, I'm sorry!

Comment: This is a very good solution, it also demonstrates the simplicity of TeX.